# Current through op-amp feedback resistor

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

*Image source: Fundamentals of Electric Circuits by Alexander and Sadiku. 5th Edition. Page 182*

Can someone explain to me how 26.25uA is the correct answer here?

I am getting 11.25uA. If I assume virtual ground at the inverting input, then apply Ohm's Law on either the 4kOhm resistor or the 280kOhm resistor. I don't even need to apply virtual ground if I assume the output is -3.15V and input is 45mV.

(45mV-0)/(4kOhm) = 11.25uA

(3.15-0)/(280kOhm) = 11.25uA

(3.15+45mV)/(280k+4k) = 11.25uA

Comment: I agree with your figure. Is there more information elsewhere, eg bias current of the opamp that would affect the answer?

Comment: @KevinWhite nope, this is it. It's just a chapter on introducing op-amps and this is one of the practice problems that I tried.

Comment: What book is it?

Comment: @KevinWhite Fundamentals of Electric Circuits by Alexander and Sadiku. 5th Edition. Page 182

Comment: That question is not the same in the book I looked at. It is presumably wrong in your edition.

Comment: Probably a typo ... (26).25  ...  (11).25

Comment: From the errata, "Practice Problem 5.3  The current through the feedback resistor is 11.25 µA."

https://highered.mheducation.com/sites/0073380571/information_center_view0/errata.html

Comment: This is a life lesson: when you’re absolutely sure you’re correct in all your works and nothing makes sense, check the errata - maybe some one else is wrong!

Comment: @GodJihyo Thanks!!!

Comment: @Bryan Unfortunately, it's usually me who is wrong :D. So I always doubt myself before doubting others - especially textbooks.

Comment: The opamp is probably an old one with a massive input current that is a little more than current in the feedback resistor.

Answer (score 1):

You found an error in the book. From the Errata for the 5th Edition:

> Practice Problem 5.3      The current through the feedback resistor is **11.25 µA.**

Link: https://highered.mheducation.com/sites/0073380571/information_center_view0/errata.html

<sub>PS: I copied this information from GodJihyo's comment as I think it is the correct answer.</sub>